# Django return a response in generic class based view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a generic class based view and  I am trying to return a response  based on some conditions but it is not happening.

```
# Create your views here.
class UserViewCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    response = HttpResponse('')

   def perform_create(self, serializer):
       if serializer.is_valid():
           if self.check_signin_details(self.request.data):
               serializer.save()
               self.response.status_code = 201
               self.response["message"] = "User created successfully."
               return self.response
           else:
               self.response.status_code = 400
               self.response["message"] = "Password or username policy failed."
               return self.response

    @staticmethod
    def check_signin_details(data):
        return len(data['username']) < 11 and len(data['userpassword']) > 10
```

I expect the response and status_code which I am setting. But I am getting a 201 everytime even on else case.   Simply put, I am not getting the custom resposne.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override `create()` method of your view,

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class UserViewCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        if self.check_signin_details(self.request.data):
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            return Response(data={"message": "User created successfully."}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(data={"message": "Password or username policy failed."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @staticmethod
    def check_signin_details(data):
        return len(data['username']) < 11 and len(data['userpassword']) < 10
```

I removed `perform_create()` method from your view, it's irrelevent here, becase, it will save the instance only if your custom username/password policy passed

Comment: Just a follow up question, create() is for saving instances. What are the other functions and their functionality ?

Comment: The `CreateAPIView` inherited by several [mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/) and those mixins contain several functions too.

Comment: [`get_serializer_class()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself)

Comment: [`is_valid()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)

Comment: The create() function internally identifies as post  method handler. What function is used for get requests ?

Comment: Since you are using `generics.CreateAPIView`, there is no option to do so by it's implementation.

Comment: If you are looking for **`CRUD`** operation, use [`ModelViewset`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) class

Answer (score 2):

`perform_create` doesn't return http response (see [source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L25)). It just saving object. You should override [`create`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L18) method if you need to modify response:

```
 def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data) 
       if serializer.is_valid():
           if self.check_signin_details(self.request.data):
               serializer.save()
               self.response.status_code = 201
               self.response["message"] = "User created successfully."
               return self.response
           else:
               self.response.status_code = 400
               self.response["message"] = "Password or username policy failed."
               return self.response
```

Comment: The solution worked for me. The only thing now is that the response["message"] is coming in response header instead of body. How do I get it  into body of the response?

Comment: @AdarshTrivedi Define response manually. Check Jerin's answer.